# Microsoft Teams Meeting Invite URL - not Join Meeting Link

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

I would like to post an "invite URL" for people to attend a Teams meeting, and I don't have the individuals email addresses. I don't want want to post the Join Meeting URL, because clicking on that closes out any meeting they might be in, and opens/joins the meeting in the link.

Does Teams support this feature or is there another way to accomplish this goal? I looked at the ics created for the meeting that Outlook creates, but that has a attendee's email address in it, i.e. is is specific to an individual.

Comment: There is no invite URL because (very) strictly speaking Teams isn't involved with that. Invites to meetings, with or without teams links, are handled by Exchange and Outlook. Invites are e-mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an email account, you can't create any Teams meetings. If you're an attendee, you can join the meeting anonymously without email. If you create a meeting, you must have an email address. You can then create a webinar in Teams that generates a registration link (similar to an invitation link, not a meeting link).

Comment: I'll wait to see if there are any other responses, but Webinar might be might option